# Creating a previous and next button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

Using AngularJS I have data that I am getting coming in the form of an array with two objects in it. I am new and trying to figure this out.

```
data[
{
"something":"something1",
"something":"something1",
"something":"something1",
},
{
"something":"something2",
"something":"something2",
"something":"something2",
}
]
```

What I want to do is create a previous and next button that when clicked the first object will change to the second object. I know using:

```
current = response.data[0];
```

will get me the first array object. I tried something like this:

```
   var current = 1
  const getSessions = () => {
    loginService.getUser().then((response) => {
      var user_id = response.data.id;
      console.log("getUser returning this => ", response.data);
      loginService.getUserSessions(user_id).then((response) => {
        current = response.data[0];
        $scope.sessions = response.data;
      })
    })
  };

 getSessions();

  $scope.nextPage = function() {
    current++;
    getSessions();
}
$scope.prevPage = function (){
    if(current > 1){
        current--;
    getSessions();    
    }
}
```

but like I said I'm not really sure what to do.

Comment: `current` will never change because you keep setting it to `response.data[0]`. Set `current` to 0 at the top and then use `response.data[current]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to increment/decrement your counter, and then set current to the currentIndex of your sessions array. I didn't test this code but I hope this helps.

```
    var current;
    var currentIndex = 0;

    const getSessions = () => {
     loginService.getUser().then((response) => {
      var user_id = response.data.id;
      console.log("getUser returning this => ", response.data);
      loginService.getUserSessions(user_id).then((response) => {
        $scope.sessions = response.data;
        current = $scope.sessions[0]
      })
     })
    };

    getSessions();

    $scope.nextPage = function() {
      if ( currentIndex < ($scope.sessions.length - 1) ) {
        currentIndex++;
        current = $scope.sessions[currentIndex]
      }
    }

    $scope.prevPage = function (){
      if ( currentIndex > 0 ) {
        currentIndex--;
        current = $scope.sessions[currentIndex]
      }
    }
```